# Verifying -sha256 signature using OpenSSL

Tags: windows, openssl, command, sha256

Maven checksum plugin generated 2 files for me:

1. Schedule.war
2. Schedule.war.sha256

On our `Windows 2008 R2` production  machine we only have `OpenSSL`, so I thought about using `OpenSSL` to verify signature against the war file. We are not allowed to install any other software.

SO far I got it to print out the on `CMD` hash of `war` file but not verify.

Can someone help me with the command to also verify?

This is what I have so far:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>openssl dgst -sha256 -signature Schedule.war.sha256 Schedule.war
SHA256(Schedule.war)= 3t4g5h6j7kf72333c2894f2942b7b5871d844b25576f7f6fif8fnf8e8w8e5
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

I just went with:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 Schedule.war
SHA256(Schedule.war)= 3t4g5h6j7kf72333c2894f2942b7b5871d844b25576f7f6fif8fnf8e8w8e5
```

And manually open .sha256 file and compare.